# Problem with FunctionInterpolation

Tags: function-construction

Plotting the function fun1 defined by

```
fun2[r_] := Integrate[Exp[r + t], {t, 0, 2}]
fun1[t_] = FunctionInterpolation[fun2[r], {r, 0, 3}]
```

a void plot is obtained: fun1 seems undefined.
How can I define fun1?

Comment: Aside from other possible issues, `fun1` passes a variable `t` which is never used in the RHS of the function...

Comment: Just by `fun1 = FunctionInterpolation[fun2[r], {r, 0, 3}]`.

Comment: ... or use  `fun1[t_] := FunctionInterpolation[fun2[r], {r, 0, 3}][t]`

Comment: @kglr But that would be even more inefficient because it would re-evaluate the `FuntcionInterpolation` (re-build the interpolating function) on every call.

Comment: @Szabolcs, right; what was i thinking?